# Why $d(x,A)$ metric is not a set?

Tags: metric-spaces, definition

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A \subseteq X $
I cannot comprehend why $d(x,A)$ is a real number. Isn’t it a set that consists of metrics between $x$ and elements of $A$?

Comment: $d(x,A)=inf\{d(x,a) : a\in A\}$

Answer (score 3):

Logically, $d(x,A)$ could be the set $\{d(x,a)\,|\,a\in A\}$. But it is usually defined as$$\inf_{a\in A}d(x,a),$$which is a real number.

Comment: Thanks I always imagine it as a set but I am sure now it is inf

Answer (score 1):

No !not at  all, d(x,A) is basically defined as the distance of the point x and the set A in the following way
$$d(x,A) =  Inf(d(x,y): y in A)$$

Which is a real no. 
 Hope it works.

Comment: Thank you. I am sure about answer now

Answer (score 1):

I can understand your confusion.  If there are many points in $A$, then it will be necessary to select one of those points to define the distance $d(x,A)$.  The most usual definition is:
$$
d(x,A)=inf_{a \in A} d(x,a)
$$
That identifies at a greatest lower bound for this distance.  For example, let $A = (0,1)$ and $X = \mathbb{R}$ with the metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$.  Then
$$
d(4, (0,1))=3.
$$ 
There are many other distances that might be defined, but all of them would satisfy the properties of a metric: (1) $d(x,y) \ge 0$ with equality if $x=y$; (2) $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$; and (3) the triangle inequality.  Still a distance is always a real number; it comes with the territory.

Comment: Thank you so much. I know it is inf but I couldn’t imagine :) Seeing your answer has been better for me